# how to store web application data on offline situation?Using android device or browser?

Tags: c#, android, .net, asp.net-mvc, offline

we are working on web application .net mvc with online clients.

> we have clients that may be offline , they are in an area without internet connectivity.

My question is , can we store their offline data with browser only, or we need other ways like using andriod application?
what is benefits of using browser offline storage or device android application?

Comment: If they are in an area without internet connectivity, how do you suppose they will be able to hit your web application?

Comment: in some places they have, when they go on their office

Comment: Why did you tagged the question on the `Android` tag ? Is the client is an `Android` device ? If yes, you can store the data on the `SQLite` database in device and upload the stored data once the network is available.

Comment: Yes , we want to suggest them to have android device, for storing in android, this is one way that I have say in my question, is there any other ways?

Comment: You need, not MVC but web API  + Executable. Collect data in EXE and when connectivity returns - work against Web API.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that, if you need to provide the capability of collecting their data offline, that solution will need to be separate from your web application. It will need to be self-contained so it can run on their device without any connectivity, and will need to provide the capability of uploading the offline data to your application once connectivity is restored. While they cannot connect to the internet, they will have no access to your web application which runs on your web server.

Comment: Ok, then what is the best way for storing offline , then sync to online? I'm hating of sync data . Is there the way that we cost low price?

Comment: If you already have a windows server to host MVC then there willbe no additional costs. Local storage on browsers is just like SQL you can store the data similar to the way you are storing it on your remote database. You can make an api call to your server to determine if the user has a connection if they do you can query all data in local storage package it into json then post it to your api. The api will map json to C# and can store it into your remote database.

Answer (score 1):

You should move away from MVC and have 2 separate websites. 1 a web api which has access to your database and 2 a single page application that runs strictly on html + javascript. Modern browsers have sql storage within the browser. You can store all offline data in this database and when there is online connection you can transfer this data to your api.